# Are there any big spring-boot open source projects?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am presently working on a spring boot application and would like to see any real-world examples of how large spring boot applications may be built.

I am particularly interested in reference to large open source projects using "spring-data-rest"

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know for example this two:

- Project Sagan: https://github.com/RameshMF/sagan
- Zipkin: https://zipkin.io/

More can be found under: https://www.javaguides.net/2018/10/free-open-source-projects-using-spring-boot.html

Comment: Thanks! After following your last link i also found [a reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/5etg0h/open_source_projects_using_spring_boot/) with similar information.

Answer (score 49):

Here are some non pet store but a real world , non trivial , and open source application that use Spring Boot 2.

1. [Thingsboard](https://thingsboard.io/) which is an IoT platform with the microservice architecture. Built with Spring Boot , Spring Security , Spring Data , Spring MVC etc.
2. [Flowable](http://www.flowable.org) is a business process engines that are based on Spring and have already upgrade to [support Spring Boot 2.0](https://blog.flowable.org/2018/04/11/the-road-to-spring-boot-2-0/)
3. [Spring Initializr](https://github.com/spring-io/initializr) is the backend web API that can quickly generate a sample spring-boot project. It is exactly the backend API that powered the famous [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/).
4. [Kafdrop](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop) is the web client that managing Kafka. Built with Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Freemarker etc.
5. [Klaw](https://www.klaw-project.io/) is another web client that managing Kafka. Built with Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Spring Security,Spring Data JPA and Thymeleaf etc.
6. The [backend](https://github.com/corona-warn-app/cwa-server) of the [Corona-Warn-App](https://www.coronawarn.app/en/) which is an app that helps trace infection chains of COVID-19 in Germany.Built with Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Spring Security,Spring Data JPA, Bean Validation etc.
7. CloudFoundry User Account and Authentication ([UAA](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa)) Server is a multi tenant identity management service used in Cloud Foundry , but also available as a stand alone OAuth2 server. Built with Spring Boot , Spring MVC , Spring Security , Spring JDBC etc.
8. [Apollo](https://github.com/apolloconfig) is the distributed configuration management system to allow you change your application 's configuration to take effect in the real time without restarting your application. Can be used to implement grayscale release too. Built with Spring Boot , Spring Cloud (e.g Eureka) , Spring Session , Spring Security , Spring MVC , Spring Data JPA etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at the [Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) project.

It is a very nice project which helps to scaffold out SpringBoot applications.

You can get an idea of many of the best practices such as security, exception-handling, logging, task-execution, repositories etc.

In short, you can scaffold out applications based on the features that you need.

Answer (score 3):

[Spring Pet Clinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic) is very good resource.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/amrkhaledccd/my-moments is an Instagram clone written in spring boot

Answer (score 2):

I know couple of Projects which are open source

[Mifos](https://mifos.org/)

[Broadleaf-Commerce](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a list of 10 `real world project demo` in this website called [code base show](https://codebase.show/projects/realworld?category=backend&language=java)

some are big project, and some are beginner-frinendly.