# Spring Batch Real World Open Source Projects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Are there any real world Spring Batch OpenSource projects? I have searched a few but they are just basic examples. I tried following the projects mentioned in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782469/are-there-any-big-spring-boot-open-source-projects) but they do not seem to have Spring Batch included.Please suggest the SpringBatch projects you know. I need to know how they have organized their code. This will help me as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. But since you are looking for how to organize the code, you can check the [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) or the [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples). They both provide a typical structure of a Spring Batch based project.